# How to set data from third-party api as siteMetaData in Gatsby?

Tags: javascript, gatsby, contentful

I want to set locales from Contentful as siteMetaData in Gatsby but I guess we can't run methods like this in gatsby-config.js during build?

```
const contentful = require("contentful")

const client = contentful.createClient({
  space: "my_space_id",
  accessToken: "my_access_token",
})

let defaultLocale = {}

// Get locales from Contentful
client.getLocales()
  .then(data =>
    data.items.forEach(item => {
      if (item.default) {
        Object.assign(defaultLocale, item)
      }
    })
  )
  .catch(err => console.log(err))

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `My site`,

    // Put locale into siteMetaData.
    defaultLocale,
  },
...
}
```

Works with `develop` but `build` fails:

```
error There was an error in your GraphQL query:
Cannot query field "defaultLocale" on type "SiteSiteMetadata".
```

I've read the [gatsby-config.js](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-config/) docs and googled. I thought about using gatsby-node.js but that doesn't seem feasible or maybe I'm not familiar enough with it.

*Update 2 March 2020*: I've also tried getting the data directly inside `siteMetadata` in gatsby-config.js:

```
{
    siteMetadata: {
        defaultLocale: () => {
                // Get and return data from Contentful
            }
  },
```

It got me the same error as before.

Then I tried taking all the configs out and running an async/await in `module.exports` in gatsby-config.js to get the Contentful data in before returning it:

```
let config = {
    siteMetadata: {
        ...
  },
  plugins: [...]
  }
}

module.exports = async () => {
    let data = await client.getLocales()
    let defaultLocale = // Get the locale data.
    config.siteMetadata["defaultLocale"] = defaultLocale
    return config
}
```

`gatsby build` complains: `A gatsby-config exported as a Function can only be used as a theme and not run directly.`

*Update 3 March 2020*: The closest I've come is with Gatsby's [setFieldsOnGraphQLNodeType](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/#setFieldsOnGraphQLNodeType) API. I've coded this into gatsby-node.js:

```
exports.setFieldsOnGraphQLNodeType = ({ type }) => {
  if (type.name === `Site`) {

    return {
      defaultLocale: {
        type: GraphQLString,
        args: {},
        resolve: (source, fieldArgs) => {
          return `Test lang.`
        },
      },
    }
  }
  return {}
}
```

In graphql playground, I can then use this query:

```
query MyQuery {
  site {
    siteMetadata {
      title
    }
    defaultLocale
  }
}
```

To get this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "site": {
      "siteMetadata": {
        "title": "My website"
      },
      "defaultLocale": "Test lang."
    }
  }
}
```

However, I can't figure out how to do it so that `defaultLocale` is nested in `siteMetadata` rather than top level in `site`. So close!

If it helps, the shape of `type` is like this:

```
{
  name: 'Site',
  nodes: [
    {
      siteMetadata: [Object],
      port: 8000,
      host: '0.0.0.0',
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

How do you set data from third-party APIs in siteMetaData?

Comment: Well, there's nothing that'd guarantee that your `defaultLocale` will be populated with the right properties before you call `module.exports`. What I'd do in this situation is use `gatsby-node.js` instead, call whatever APIs you need and set the context to have the `siteMetadata` property with the values that you need.

Comment: @goto1 Thanks. I'm looking through [gatsby-node docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/) but can't see an appropriate API. Which one is it that sets siteMetaData from gatsby-node.js?

Comment: Actually, it looks like the `context` I was taking about can be used when you're creating pages inside `gatsby-node.js`, i.e. blog posts that use a template. Pages inside of the `pages` directory wouldn't take advantage of it.

Comment: @goto1 Ah, I see. Thanks for clarifying. I did briefly think of making the navbar into pages with locales in them but that would mean using it as an iframe rather than a component. Probably won't do that though.

Comment: I am wondering if a custom plugin would do the trick here for your case - https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/11128#issuecomment-458607853. Inside `gatsby-node.js` it looks like its doable without the plugin but not in `gatsby-config.js`.

Comment: @goto1 I don't know how to build a custom plugin yet. I guess I'll have to circle back on this one if I have more time. But thanks for the link. It allows me to accept maybe it's not possible to do this right now and to move on.